# Прозрачный текст с белым бордером

Tags: css, svg, текст

Каким образом достичь данного результата?

[image: Фото]

Способы:

```
color: rgba(255,255,255,0.01)
background-clip
color: transparent + text-shadow
```

Не дали результатов

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно с помощью svg:

```css
body {
  background: #b4e391;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg, #b4e391 0%, #61c419 50%, #b4e391 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, #b4e391 0%, #61c419 50%, #b4e391 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, #b4e391 0%, #61c419 50%, #b4e391 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#b4e391', endColorstr='#b4e391', GradientType=1);
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 500 80">
 <text y="50" fill="transparent"
    font-size="50px" 
    font-weight="bold"
    stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="1">Ваш текст</text>
</svg>
```

Comment: можно ещё проще stroke="#FFFFFF" fill="none"

Comment: @Alexandr_TT точно, ну я все таки дитя css)

Comment: @kizoso , для какого IE этот аццкий фильтр: `progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#b4e391', endColorstr='#b4e391', GradientType=1)` ?

Comment: для IE6-9, я олдфаг)))))

Answer (score 2):

Используйте значение `rgba()` для свойства `color`

```css
div {
  font-family: Arial Black, Arial Bold, Gadget, sans-serif;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
  font-size: 80px;
  margin-left: 25px;
  text-shadow: -1px 0 black, 0 1px black, 1px 0 black, 0 -1px black;
}
```

```html
<div>Некоторый текст</div>
```

Или вы можете использовать `:pseudo-element`.

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  font-family: Arial Black, Arial Bold, Gadget, sans-serif;
  font-size: 80px;
  margin-left: 25px;
  text-shadow: -1px 0 black, 0 1px black, 1px 0 black, 0 -1px black;
}

div:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left:0;
  content: 'Некоторый текст';
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: Arial Black, Arial Bold, Gadget, sans-serif;
  color: white;
  opacity: 0.4;
  font-size: 80px;
  z-index: 1;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div>Некоторый текст</div>
```

Или вы можете использовать `SVG`.

```css
body, html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/500/200/) no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<svg width="460" height="100">
  <text fill="white" fill-opacity="0.4" font-size="60" x="240" y="70" text-anchor="middle" stroke="black">Некоторый текст</text>
</svg>
```

Перевод [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28130295/transparent-text-with-a-border-html-css/28130324#28130324) со [Stack Overflow на английском](https://stackoverflow.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй с помощью псевдо элементов:

```
div { 
position: relative; 
font-family: Arial Black, Arial Bold, Gadget, sans-serif; 
font-size: 80px; 
margin-left: 25px; 
text-shadow: -1px 0 black, 0 1px black, 1px 0 black, 0 -1px black; 
} 

div:after { 
position: absolute; 
top: 0; 
left:0; 
content: 'Some text'; 
width: 100%; 
height: 100%; 
font-family: Arial Black, Arial Bold, Gadget, sans-serif; 
color: white;
opacity: 0.4; 
font-size: 80px; 
z-index: 1; 
pointer-events: none; 
}
```

[Источник](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28130324/4772782) с другими решениями